# dup entry when doing insert into mysql from perl

Tags: mysql, perl, insert, dbi

i'm doing an insert into a mysql db from perl. i'm getting a duplicate error after the 1st insert. here is the code i'm using for the insert. i'm pulling an id from a json response. i have output of what i'm receiving below the code

```
  foreach my $listing(@{$json_text->{listings}})
    {
      my $id = $listing->{id};
   print "\nid = $id \n";


    # DO THE INSERT
    my $query_insert = "INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES ($id)";
    print "query insert = $query_insert \n";
    my $query = $db->do($query_insert); 
   print "query = $query \n";

    } #end foreach
```

here is the output i'm receiving. (returns didn't copy over right. so the below looks off, but the right data is there). this is like 133
            my $query = $db->do($query_insert);

id = 2576246314 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576246314) 
query = 1

id = 2576246678 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576246678) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

id = 2576246781 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576246781) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

id = 2576247610 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576247610) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

id = 2576247737 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576247737) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

id = 2576247756 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576247756) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

id = 2576247766 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576247766) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

id = 2576248369 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576248369) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

id = 2576248388 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576248388) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

id = 2576248660 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576248660) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

id = 2576249706 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576249706) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

id = 2576250254 
query insert = INSERT INTO calendar (id) VALUES (2576250254) 
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./calendar_run.pl line 133.
query =

Comment: We need to see what the table structure of calendar looks like

Comment: PLEASE use DBI placeholders in your code. Right now anybody can pwn your DB by putting funny stuff in your JSON. http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like the type for id is too short. That value in your "duplicate entry" message (2147483647) is the maximum signed 32-bit integer value. Try using a larger size for ID.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using DBD::MySQL. Here is what I found: "Perl stores returned values as strings, but will automatically convert them to numbers when you use the values in a numeric context. This will cause them to be "truncated" to 2147483647 since Perl uses a signed LONG value to store such numbers." (here: http://www.tol.it/doc/MySQL/chapter7.html).
But I haven't found any public bug for it.